# How to get a string after the nth "-" (dash) in java?

Tags: java, string

Supposedly, I have a string called c with "BPI-1111-2203-4493" stored in it.

```
String c = "BPI-1111-2203-4493";
```

I would now like to split this string into two strings like this:

```
String one = "BPI";
String two = "1111-2203-4493";
```

I have tried to use this:

```
String[] b = bank.split("-"); 
String one = b[0];
String two = b[1];
```

but the strings ends up like this:

```
String one = "BPI";
String two = "1111";
```

what String function should I use so that string two will have "1111-2203-4493" and not "1111" only.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `indexOf` and `substring`?

Comment: @JonSkeet That would be easy if I know which `-`. But what about the "_nth `-`_"

Comment: You can call `indexOf` multiple times, passing in the result of the previous call each time to move along. (Look at the overload of `indexOf` that takes an initial index.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can split with limit

```
String c = "BPI-1111-2203-4493";
String[] s = c.split("-", 2);
```

Comment: Question was how to split on nth dash, e.g. n=2 means `BPI-1111` and `2203-4493`.

Comment: @Andreas then you can just do `c.split("-", 3)[2]` that will give you `2203-4493`

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to use the `subString` and `indexOf` methods as follows :

```
String c = "BPI-1111-2203-4493";
String one = c.subString(0, c.indexOf('-'));
String two = c.subString(c.indexOf('-') + 1, c.length());
```

Comment: Question was how to split on nth dash, e.g. n=2 means `BPI-1111` and `2203-4493`.

Answer (score 1):

To split after the n'th dash, use a regular expression to find the point to split on and call `substring()`. Just change the number between `{}` for the appropriate n value.

```
(?:[^-]*-){2}
```

Here is demo with all 3 n's:

```
String input = "BPI-1111-2203-4493";
Matcher m;

// Split on 1st dash
m = Pattern.compile("(?:[^-]*-){1}").matcher(input);
if (m.find())
    System.out.printf("%s, %s%n", input.substring(0, m.end() - 1),
                                  input.substring(m.end()));

// Split on 2nd dash
m = Pattern.compile("(?:[^-]*-){2}").matcher(input);
if (m.find())
    System.out.printf("%s, %s%n", input.substring(0, m.end() - 1),
                                  input.substring(m.end()));

// Split on 3rd dash
m = Pattern.compile("(?:[^-]*-){3}").matcher(input);
if (m.find())
    System.out.printf("%s, %s%n", input.substring(0, m.end() - 1),
                                  input.substring(m.end()));
```

Output:

```
BPI, 1111-2203-4493
BPI-1111, 2203-4493
BPI-1111-2203, 4493
```

---

That can easily be turned into a reusable helper method:

```
private static String[] split(String input, char ch, int n) {
    if (n <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be >0");
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?:[^" + ch + "]*" + ch + "){" + n + "}").matcher(input);
    if (! m.find())
        return new String[] { input };
    return new String[] { input.substring(0, m.end() - 1),
                          input.substring(m.end()) };
}
```

Test:

```
String input = "BPI-1111-2203-4493";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split(input, '-', 1)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split(input, '-', 2)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split(input, '-', 3)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split(input, '-', 4)));
```

Output:

```
[BPI, 1111-2203-4493]
[BPI-1111, 2203-4493]
[BPI-1111-2203, 4493]
[BPI-1111-2203-4493]
```

---

Or you can follow [suggestion by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255460/how-to-get-a-string-after-the-nth-dash-in-java/37255522?noredirect=1#comment62038251_37255460) and use [`indexOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-int-):

```
private static String[] split(String input, char ch, int n) {
    if (n <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be >0");
    int idx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if ((idx = input.indexOf(ch, idx) + 1) == 0)
            return new String[] { input };
    return new String[] { input.substring(0, idx - 1),
                          input.substring(idx) };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that in your case the split method will return an array with four items on it:

```
b[0] = "BPI"
b[1] = "1111"
b[2] = "2203"
b[3] = "4493"
```

I would suggest a similar approach of some of the previous answers but with some error checking first:

```
String c = "BPI-1111-2203-4493";
String one = null;
String two = null;
if((null != c)) {
    int firstDashIndex = c.indexOf('-');
    if(firstDashIndex >= 0) {
        one = c.substring(0, firstDashIndex);
        if((firstDashIndex + 1) < c.length()) {
            two = c.substring(firstDashIndex + 1);
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(one);
System.out.println(two);
```

Hope it helps.